# Google Chrome vertical space above rendered font issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

Google Chrome renders font differently than Safari with regards to space above text. How can I make the Chrome one look like the Safari one? This change seems to be introduced recently in Chrome (i.e it used to work).

HTML

```
<span>LARGE</span>
```

CSS

```
span {
    font-size: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p0wuz901/

Chrome version: (OS X - Version 40.0.2214.91 (64-bit)) 
[image: Chrome]

Safari version: (OS X - Version 8.0.2 (10600.2.5))
[image: Safari]

Comment: have you tried setting the `line-height` to `1` as an example ?

Comment: @Danko It makes no difference. Even if you normalize the css (there's an option in the Fiddle) there's still some alignment issues. It seems to me as though the baseline for the font itself is the issue... Not sure if Safari/Chrome are using their own versions of that font.

Comment: FWIW Chrome and Firefox match. It looks like Safari is the odd man out here.

Comment: Yikes! If the trend is towards rendering it like Chrome does. The cause of this issue is that vertically centered layouts using flexbox no longer look centered for large text content, instead they look so much off they look like crap.